# Position of prepositional phrases

Tags: prepositional-phrases

From a book

> It will be evident that poet’s function is not to report things that have happened, but rather to tell of such things as might happen , things that are possibilities by virtue of being in themselves inevitable or probable.

‘Being in themselves inevitable or probable’
Does the meaning change if the PP goes behind?
‘Being inevitable or probable in themselves’

Answer (score 1):

Short but definitive answer: no.